# How can I get an NSDate representation of a specific hour in the day of another NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to get an `NSDate` for a specific hour of the day based on another `NSDate`. For example, if I have an `NSDate` representing a known time on May 10th, 2015, I need to be able to get an `NSDate` representing 01:00 on May 10th, 2015.

How would I go about doing this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSCalendar` to get the `NSDateComponents` from your initial `NSDate`. You can then change individual fields in the `NSDateComponents`. Finally, use `NSCalendar` to convert back to an `NSDate`.

For example:

```
let now = NSDate()
var components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: now)

println(now)

components.hour = 1
components.minute = 0
components.second = 0

let updated = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)
println(updated)
```

Answer (score 1):

NSCalendar already has a method called dateBySettingHour() that allows you to that:

```
let inputDate = NSDate()
let resultDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(1, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: inputDate, options: nil)!
```

Comment: Hm, okay, I'll consider this too. Thanks!